# Reusing one BufferedWriter instance for one file along application lifetime

Tags: java, multithreading, bufferedwriter

I have a multi-threading application where some of my threads should read data from queue and write them to a file. The problem here is that I am confusing should I create new BufferedWriter instance every time when one of my threads reads value from queue and writes it to same file or I can have just one BufferedWriter instance and `flush()` every time. One problem in second solution is that I should detect when I should close the BufferedWriter without using Java 7 perfect solution for closing resources in `try-catch` block.

Does the second solution solves some performance issues?
What are best practices on this?

Comment: Who was -1 this? I am still waiting comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using one `BufferedWriter` for writing to the file that is shared by all threads.  For the sake of performance, the `BufferedWriter` should be kept open until the application decides that there is no more output. (Opening and closing files is relatively expensive.)

You also need to have the application threads use some kind of locking (e.g. synchronize on the `BufferedWriter`) to ensure that they don't try to write at the same time.  The `BufferedWriter` class is not thread-safe.

The try/finally or try-with-resources approach to managing file resources is important in cases where you are opening lots of files.  If you are only dealing with one file, and it needs to be open for the entire duration of the application, then resource management is not so critical.  (But you do need to make sure that you either close or flush before the application exits.)

---

> But I think BufferedWriter is thread-safe, because underlying implementation of write() methods using synchronized blocks

Well in that sense, yes it is.  However, that assumes that when your thread writes data, it does it in a single `write(...)` call.

Note also that `BufferedWriter` is not *specified* to be thread-safe, even if it is thread-safe in the current implementation.

Comment: I second this solution. But it is a bit tricky to implement unless you have hard facts about 'when the data in the queue for the file is done'

Comment: @Stephen C Thanks for your suggestion. Yes I think too that it will be relatively expensive to open and close files every time. But I think BufferedWriter is thread-safe, because underlying implementation of write() methods using synchronized blocks

Comment: @Nazgul - I'm assuming  that the application is coded to simply closes the file when it exits.

Comment: @Nazgul I have one solution for that hard fact, simply checking count of alive threads and closing the writer when latest thread is getting interupted.

Comment: @Stephen C Yes that is an important thing to note that BufferedWriter is thread-safe in only some context. Thanks!

Comment: @ArsenAlexanyan: not a good way to do it. Probably a barrier or a latch would be helpful in that regard. Counting threads is not an ok approach.

Comment: @StephenC: Right. Thats a valid assumption in this case.

Comment: @Nazgul Yes I agree it's not an ok solution. My requirments was to save the data even if program is terminated normally. So I am implemented it by registering shutdown hook thread. And I am closing my buffered writer there.

Answer (score 1):

A BufferedWriter should ever lead to one file/Writer/OutputStream; if you have many targets you will need many buffers. If you want to write to the same file from multiple threads you will need to synchronize on the earliest bit; you can synchronized on the BufferredWriter if you don't have more high-level constructs that the character stream. If you synchronize on the BufferedWriter, you will not need to call flush() after the end of each access.